# How to localize(Multilingual) javascript string in drupal 7 which included as inline?

Tags: javascript, drupal, localization, drupal-7

I am looking for a solution to localize my javascript file which written inline in my drupal 7 project.

Everything which I wrote in the javascript file could convert to the specific language using `Drupal.t("String")`, but javascript which included as inline would not.

How to solve this issue..?

Comment: Did you clear the cache? Just to be sure.

Comment: Yup, I have cleared the Drupal cache, Its working fine with the JavaScript file. Issue  found only with the inline JavaScript file which I have included through the module file.